# How do I blacklist certain directories in Samba?

Tags: server, samba

I am exporting a directory via Samba to my home theater PC. Unfortunately XBMC is also displaying some working directories that I happen to be sharing inside that directory.

I would like to find a way to have Samba ignore certain directories so that they are not shared with the other PCs.

This is purely for vanity reasons so the solution doesn't need to be totally perfect (So a workaround would be fine, it doesn't have to be production quality)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm thinking [`veto files`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#VETOFILES) is the option you're looking for.

Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` with root rights. Under the particular share `/var/test`, the following setting will exclude any descendant sub-directory or file matching `foo` or `*bar*` (beware, `/` means **OR**):

```
[myshare]
  path = /var/test
  veto files = /foo/*bar*/
```

Then, you need to restart Samba with `stop` and `start` (not `reload`):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba stop
sudo /etc/init.d/samba start
```

Note: Shares created through Nautilus GUI are defined in individual files in `/var/lib/samba/usershare` but `veto files` **can't be applied there**. If it's your case:

- Either add `veto files` to the `[global]` section of `/var/lib/samba/usershare`. This will affect to all your global shares.
- Or delete the existing share definition file under `/var/lib/samba/usershare` and re-create it manually under `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. You can't copy paste; instead, [follow the guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!).

Comment: The `/` character in the `veto files` pattern is not a directory separator. In the example above, provided you add a `/` at the end to make it syntactically correct, any files or directories named either `var`, `test` or `private` will be hidden.

Comment: samba can read lists in "veto files"?  https://serverfault.com/questions/923647/samba-multiple-lines-in-veto-files

Answer (score 3):

`hide files = file1/file2/$*/System Volume Information` also hides the folder from share